# Extracting multiple value using xmlstarlet

Tags: xmlstarlet

How can I extract "failed" from all element and add them up?

```
<gateway>
    <smscs>
        <count>3</count>
        <smsc>
            <id>a</id>
            <received><sms>0</sms><dlr>0</dlr></received>
            <sent><sms>10537</sms><dlr>0</dlr></sent>
            <failed>13</failed>
            <queued>6272</queued>
        </smsc>
        <smsc>
            <id>b</id>
            <received><sms>0</sms><dlr>0</dlr></received>
            <sent><sms>10530</sms><dlr>0</dlr></sent>
            <failed>10</failed>
            <queued>6284</queued>
        </smsc>
        <smsc>
            <id>c</id>
            <received><sms>0</sms><dlr>0</dlr></received>
            <sent><sms>10679</sms><dlr>0</dlr></sent>
            <failed>11</failed>
            <queued>6291</queued>
        </smsc>
    </smscs>
</gateway>
```

Comment: Able to extract them in lines with `xmlstarlet sel -t -m "gateway/smscs/smsc/failed" -v "." -n`

Answer (score 4):

I simply used

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "sum(/gateway/smscs/smsc/failed)" -n input.xml
```

which returned

```
34
```

The idea is to use the [`sum()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-sum) function which takes a node-set and returns the sum of all the elements' string-values converted to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "gateway/smscs/smsc/failed" -v "." -n | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```